# Client Specific Dynamic Urls with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an app and within the app clients will be allowed to have many specific urls for themselves that they can add to their own sub domain.

So for instance they'll have a subdomain and have a monthly competition.

subdomain.client1.com/myJuneComp/

subdomain.client1.com/myJuneComp/thankyou

subdomain.client1.com/myJulyComp/

subdomain.client1.com/myJulyComp/thankyou

subdomain.client1.com/randomComp

subdomain.client1.com/randomComp/thankyou

I'm wondering what the best way to implement this in asp.net mvc would be. It will also be mixed with the application administration.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to your actions for the client (eg, `string clientName`), then add `{clientName}/` to the beginning of every relevant route URL.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I'm talking about dynamically generated urls. Not static routes.

Comment: @James: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  If you want the URLs to be more dynamic, just add more route parameters.